# Error while running executable created by PyInstaller

Tags: python, scipy, keras, executable, pyinstaller

I ran into an error while using PyInstaller on Ubuntu.

The script imports tkinter, PIL, tensorflow, numpy, keras, matplotlib, and cv2.

This is the error message I get when I try to run the executable created by PyInstaller. I'm using Python 3.6.4 and PyInstaller 3.3.1.

Alternatively, are there any other methods to create a standalone executable from a Python script?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "keras/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "keras/datasets/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "keras/datasets/imdb.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "keras/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "keras_preprocessing/image.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy/ndimage/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy/ndimage/filters.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy/ndimage/_ni_docstrings.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy/misc/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "stringsource", line 104, in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd
AttributeError: type object 'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
[15453] Failed to execute script main
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this seems to be a lot of errors, so for start: Error isn't probably caused by interpreting to .exe, but in code itself. Is the code working inside the IDE? If so, also consider that pyinstaller doesn't include other files which program needs to run *(e.g. imported icons, images etc.)*. Furthermore, **error in second last line is indicating that something is indeed wrong with the original code**... When you execute the code in IDE it doesn't have to be a problem, because it crashes only when you explicitly come to the point with error, but the pyinstaller's output "*runs everything in a loop*" so it won't even start... I hope I helped You :)